# C++ operator overloading adding 3 vectors together

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, operator-keyword

For now this is how I add 3 vectors of type Product together:

```
    vector1.insert(std::end(vector1), std::begin(vector2), std::end(vector2));
    vector1.insert(std::end(vector1), std::begin(vector3), std::end(vector3));
```

How do I use operator overloading (I assume overloading the + and = operators) to simplify my code? Product has the following properties:

```
private:
    std::string url;
    double cost;
    std::string name;
    std::string site;
```

Comment: Why do you think you want to use operator overloading for this task? And have you made any sort of an attempt?

Comment: I know how to use operator overloading to add the costs of 2 Products together but I am not sure how to do it for vectors.

Comment: What's your goal? `vector1 += vector2 + vector3` or something else?

Comment: C++ operators are (mostly) binary operators. Your operation is ternary; it has 3 operands. **operator overloading is totally the wrong tool here.** just write a function `merge_vectors_inplace(vector1, vector2, vector3)` or similar.

Comment: Your code is just fine as is. Inserting custom wrappers for the standard library when using it directly is easy just makes your code less readable.

Comment: p.s. What I'm referring to as a bad idea would be a result like `vector_append(vector1, vector2); vector_append(vector1, vector2);` or `vector1 += vector2; vector1 += vector3;`. Note that it is unexpected for `+=` to be defined for vectors.

Comment: @DanielJour: It's quite clearly nestable though. The OP is already doing a "binary" operation twice. While I'm not convinced operator overloading is the appropriate solution here, it's not because there are three inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating overloading is just a normal free function, or member function.

There's nothing special about them, mostly.  (The "mostly" referring to operator precedence and some caveats for things like `operator*` dereferencing or `operator,`.)

Here is an example using `operator+=` and `append` showing they do the same thing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::begin;
using std::cout;
using std::end;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::vector;

struct Product
{
  static int count;
  int i;
  Product() : i{++count} {}
};

static ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Product const& p)
{
  o << p.i;
  return o;
}

int Product::count = 100;

static void append(vector<Product>& v, vector<Product> const& v2)
{
  v.insert(end(v), begin(v2), end(v2));
}

static vector<Product>& operator+=(vector<Product>& v, vector<Product> const& v2)
{
  v.insert(end(v), begin(v2), end(v2));
  return v;
}

int main()
{
  auto product1 = vector<Product>{};
  product1.push_back(Product{});
  product1.push_back(Product{});
  product1.push_back(Product{});
  product1.push_back(Product{});

  auto product2 = vector<Product>{};
  product2.push_back(Product{});
  product2.push_back(Product{});
  product2.push_back(Product{});
  product2.push_back(Product{});

  auto product3 = vector<Product>{};
  product3.push_back(Product{});
  product3.push_back(Product{});
  product3.push_back(Product{});
  product3.push_back(Product{});

  append(product1, product2);
  product1 += product3;

  char const* sep = "";
  for (auto const& p : product1)
  {
    cout << sep << p;
    sep = " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This needs a discussion of namespaces and ADL, and probably why std did not overload these operators and why end users cannot do it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I would not assume overloading operations for standard containers as a good idea. However, I would write a function to concatenate a bunch of vectors. Having a C++11 you can use `std::initializer_list` to have the argument lists of a variable length with ease.

```
// your includes ...
#include <initializer_list>

// some code ...

std::vector<Product> concatVectors(std::initializer_list<std::vector<Product>> args)
{
    std::vector<Product> res;
    for (auto v: args) {
        res.insert(std::end(res), std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    }
    return res;
}
```

And then call this function like that:

```
vector1 = concatVectors({vector1, vector2, vector3});
```

Curly braces initialize a new instance of `std::initializer_list` and that works like magic for any number of vectors.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but ils are const and contain values, and thus this forces 2 copies of all data (into il and out).  A well written function will copy at most once (plus maybe some for expinential resize).