# Adding multiple vectors of same size in constructor using an equation form

Tags: c++

Is it possible to add/subtract more than two,ideally three vector/matrix coefficients in constructor of a class?

Ideally, I would like to achieve something like this which is called in main file of the open source openfoam fluid dynamics solver:

```
            tmp<fvVectorMatrix> tUEqn
            (
                fvm::ddt(U) +  fvm::div(phi, U)
              + turbulence->divDevReff(U) 
               == 
               fvOptions(U)
            );
```

My guess is that the constructor has multiple operator overloading done since this equation is described in the main file. 
Here the matrix coefficients resulting from  fvm::ddt(U), fvm::div(phi,U), and turbulence->divDevReff(U) are added together to the coefficient of fvVectorMatrix which is a template type of fvMatrix class.
How can I achieve something like this?

EDIT:

So after 3 days of trying stuff i finally solved this issue:
Here is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


using namespace std;

class Fields
{
    public:
        Fields():value(1.0){
        };
        double value;
        typedef vector<Fields> vecFields;

};

 Fields::vecFields operator+(const Fields::vecFields& lhs, const Fields::vecFields& rhs)
 {
     Fields::vecFields result(lhs);
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < lhs.size(); i++)
        {
            result[i].value += rhs[i].value;
        }
        return result;
 }

int main()
{

    vector<Fields> fvec1(4);
    vector<Fields> fvec2(4);
    vector<Fields> fvec3(4);

       fvec3= fvec1+fvec2+fvec3;

     for(unsigned int i=0; i<fvec1.size();i++)
     {
         cout << fvec3[i].value << endl;
     }
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Not without operator overloading, you can't.

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601019/c-operator-overloading-adding-3-vectors-together

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You should tell the compiler how to add/subtract/divide vectors/matrixes. So you should overload corresponding operators.

You might achieve same behaviour with function calls unless you want to use '+,-,/,*' operators.

You can implement required operators by the help of 
[operator overloading](http://%20https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The vector/matrix is a vector of objects holding data type double in the end. I have successfully overloaded two vectors of objects/class. But when it comes to three I am not sure what to do. But I will have a look around in the website you suggested. thank you

Comment: @LionelRiz If you properly declare your function this should work. result = fvm::ddt(U) + fvm::div(phi,U) + turbulence->divDevReff(U); Did you tried?

Comment: Could you edit your question and share your work ? So we could help you better. For now, it is not possible to say which piece of code is working or what is absent/wrong.